# Demyltiplexing camera outputs in deepstream on different ports

Tags: python, kubernetes, gpu, deepstream

I am using deepstream for video analytics on multiple cameras. When I need to see the individual output from each of these cameras on a web page I need to demultiplex them. This demultiplexing requires multiple node ports( kubernetes on GPU is the environment used).

However there is a limitation on the number of nodeports I can use. Can anybody suggest me some way out of this

Thanks in advance.  Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We have tried using multiple nodeports. But we have a limitations on the number of ports so we cannot use this approach